# Is there any shloka against public display of affection for humans in Kaliyuga?

Tags: sex, human

Are there any statements in Hindu scriptures that forbid or discourage public display of affection or public romance other than Narada Muni curse on Nalakubara and Mangriva?

If there are specific references that applies to only Kaliyuga, please provide them.

In general most of the species other than humans exhibit public sex, so specify any mentions that either support or reject public display of affection by **only humans**.

Comment: No there are no Sloks actually telling us not to show public affection as such in the direct way but as we know sanskrit can sometimes be confusing to uderstand and thus the people sometimes misinterpret the actual deep meaning about the thing really meant by the writer

Comment: What is your edit actually? There is nothing showing up in the revision history.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I edited for long time.

Comment: revision 2 had nothing in it. Only revision 3 has the modification.